# Is Twinkle twinkle little star based on a drone/bourdon?

Tags: harmony

Is Twinkle twinkle little star based on a drone/bourdon?
If you say no then what is it based on?

Comment: Drone in English but bourdon in french.

Comment: "In music, a [drone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(music)) is a harmonic or monophonic effect or accompaniment where a note or chord is continuously sounded throughout most or all of a piece."

Answer (score 4):

I’ve just played it on bagpipes so it certainly works with a drone, but I don't think it’s particularly based on a drone, no.

It’s more based on straightforward open up and down chords if anything.

Comment: What are open up and down chords?

Comment: Arpeggios is the word I was struggling for! Although really it's pretty much all chromatic runs apart from the I - V leap at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can! (of course not the variations by Mozart)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Variations_on_%22Ah_vous_dirai-je,_Maman%22

Actually there can play every tune based on I IV V accompanied  with a drone as example the canon "frère Jacques" can be harmonized I V I or just with a drone... another known example with more chords is "amazing grace"

Comment: You can add a drone to just about any melody with at least interesting results. :)

Comment: yes, "joyful, joyful" will work too ;)

Comment: In der Tat.  Unisono kommen wir weiter. Wenigstens als Anfang. :)